# Downloading free Microsoft VMs with Internet Explorer fails at ~1.5GB-2GB every time

Tags: virtual-machine, internet-explorer

I've been trying for over a week to download Microsoft free VMs for testing a website in different versions of Internet Explorer, but download fails everytime.

Website: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Example download url for on specific VM: https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/VMBuild_20150916/VirtualBox/IE9/IE9.Win7.VirtualBox.zip

Also, downloads are not restartable, download speed never exceeds 100kb, and it doesn't support download accelerators splitting the download in multiple parts.

I live in Brazil, and tried it in different locations, no luck.

Any workarounds, alternate official download urls, or fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain `az792536.vo.msecnd.net` can resolve to different ip addresses depending on where in the world you are. The download speed and also whether or not it is possible to resume the download will depend on that address.

Put the following entry into the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
152.199.20.1 az792536.vo.msecnd.net
```

And then try again to download `https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/VMBuild_20150916/VirtualBox/IE9/IE9.Win7.VirtualBox.zip`

Comment: To get the ip address indepently and in a trustable manner, I ended up starting up an amazon windows EC2 machine, in US region, and pinging the address from there. There are probably easier ways, but this is the one I came up with (not sure which VPNs can I trust for this kind of data).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to download Microsoft SQL Server in Australia , it automatically got resolved after a week or two. In the meantime I used an old version of SQLServer. I think it's usually an issue with the Server nearest to your location.

You can try the below:

- Download while connected to a VPN .
- Download during a different time of the day.
- This site gives you free 7 day trial https://crossbrowsertesting.com/offer/web-testing , you can use it till the issue is resolved.
- Also as per this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2015/09/08/4-ways-to-test-your-website-in-old-versions-of-ie/), 
  I quote:  *IE8, IE9, IE10 and IE11 all have developer tools that you can access by pressing F12 whilst in Internet Explorer. These allow you to change your document and browser mode to go back to older rendering engines, which you can find on the emulation tab in the tools.*

Comment: Answer was very complete! But the accepted answer pointed me to just find an alternative ip address and use hosts file to point to that, without the need of downloading through a VPN, which eventually solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thats cool, glad you found a solution